# How to read the content of a csv file from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, csv, servlets

```
JSP File
-------------
<form method="post" id="bulk-form" action="/pc/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="${param.product}" />
    <input type="file" multiple name="fname">
    <input type="submit" class="btn red-btn" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>

Servlet
-----------
String param = request.getParameter("product");

DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

try {
    // Parse the request to get file items.
    List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
    System.err.println("Got fileItems "+fileItems);
}
catch(Exception e){

}
```

In the above code the `request.getParameter("product")` returns the correct output but the `fileItems` is empty.

If hidden form is not used then `request.getParameter("product")` shows Connection terminated for `multipart` data.

Comment: You forget to name the `<input type="file" multiple name='files'>`.

Comment: It still shows the same exception

Comment: Read this - [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1)